# How to make two buttons appear underneath each other in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I make two buttons appear underneath each other in a dropdown menu of Javascript? This is the code that I tried but they appear next to each other:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>&nbsp;Registeration Menu&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a id="btn-register" href="#">User</a>

                    <a id="btn-registerAdmin" href="#">Admin</a>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Did those links not want to be wrapped in `<li>` elements?

Comment: No. When I wrap them in <li> elements, they appear next to each other. E.g., User Admin. Which i something that I do not want to happen.

Comment: I don't think it is valid HTML to have `<a>` tags in a `<ul>` tag,  the only thing that cat go in is `<li>`s.  but ignoring that but a `<br>` at the end of the first link.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li><a id="btn-register" href="#">User</a></li>
<li><a id="btn-registerAdmin" href="#">Admin</a></li>

Add <li> tags.
```

Comment: I was going to say it may be a problem with your CSS . But if it fixed it... sweet!